# Sqlite - Select distinct from two column

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select, distinct

My goal is to create a messenger application .

I have a **SQLITE** db in client side like this :

```
ID      sender      receiver      text
AI      1           3             ****
AI      3           1             ****
AI      3           1             ****
AI      1           3             ****
AI      3           1             ****
AI      1           3             ****
AI      1           2             ****
```

My output SELECT should be :

```
3 , 1 , 2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `union` operator implicitly applies the distinct modifier on the query, so it could be as simple as:

```
SELECT sender
FROM   messages
UNION
SELECT receiver
FROM   messages
```

Comment: I forgot that DISTINCT isn't required when you use UNION, because UNION already gets rid of duplicate values.  (Deleted my answer.)

Comment: Is this query select last inserted row ? I mean this query fetch Bigger id ?

Comment: I need to select another columns in this query . have a solution ?